# How to add Crypto++ library to NS3 using waf build system?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, signature, ssl, simulation

Steps I've performed:

1. I already downloaded the crypto++ 8.8.0 source code & moved them to a folder called `cryptopp`.
2. Furthermore, I have also created a `wscript` file in the `cryptopp` folder.

How should I proceed further?

Further details about my situation can be found at this link: https://pastebin.com/XrauDUCk